# Java bounded type parameters in interface implementation

Tags: java, spring

I want to combine the use of bounded type parameters with DI spring. That is, I would like to declare an interface:

```java
public abstract class BaseClass {
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
}

public interface SomeInterface {
    <T extends BaseClass> void update(T impl);
}
```

and make its implementation:

```java
@Service
public class Impl1 extends SomeInterface {
    @Override
    void update(ChildClass impl) {
    }
}
```

That is, I want to declare in the interface a general type condition for implementations and use a specific type of successor in the implementation.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your interface could have a generic parameter for the type of BaseClass it applies to. `interface SomeInterface<T extends BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T extends BaseClass> {

    void update(T impl);

}
```

and then:

```
@Service
public class Impl1 extends SomeInterface<ChildClass> {
    @Override
    void update(ChildClass impl) {

    }
}
```